# Error after cloning 50% of a 50k+ commit svn repository to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

When trying to migrate an svn repository with 50k+ commits to git using the following commands:

```
git init
git svn init https://10.10.10.10:8443/svn/rep --stdlayout
git svn fetch --fetch-all --log-window-size=1000 --authors-file=..\authors-transform.txt
```

the following error is reported:

```
Connection reset by peer: Error running context: Connection reset by peer at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.
```

I've already tried to fetch again, but the error persists.

- git: 2.12.12
- svn: 1.8.11
- os: windows 7 x64

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? You can download the files locally and then do the conversion.

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and then only Git will be used, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: @msitt I have access to the server but what would you do locally?

Comment: @Vampire One time migration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout and you can also tell it to keep empty directories by giving it a commandline option that causes it to put empty `.gitignore` files in the directories to keep them.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: No thoughts of "why" the `Connection reset by peer ...  line 312` error is thrown or how to solve it??

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you really need to use `git-svn` because you just want to use it client-side, you have to investigate why the remote end closes the connection. Could be from a proxy in-between not liking the request up to some timeout or bug. For a one-time migration, just use the proper tool and you don't have the `git-svn` quirks. :-)