# GIt Migration clone failing

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Trying to clone  and it is failing printing:

```
Connection reset by peer: Error running context: Connection reset by peer
```

Tried `git svn fetch` but still it is not working

Comment: CAn u please paste full log? is it occur after a while or right away?

Comment: (refs/remotes/git-svn)
Connection reset by peer: Error running context: Connection reset by peer at /mi
ngw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.

Comment: it occurs after a while

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615825/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use regular svn commands such as svn list?  If you are still getting the same error, it may be a typo in your URL or something to do with your network.